# Find the inside of a Loop

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid

## Task

Given a ASCII diagram of a loop

*e.g.*

```
....................
......@@@@@.........
......@...@.........
.....@@...@@@@@.....
....@@........@.....
....@........@@.....
....@@@@@@@@@@......
....................
....................
```

And a location on the loop

*e.g.*

```
(7,1)
```

You must find the inside and outside of the loop

*e.g.*

```
00000000000000000000
00000011111000000000
00000011111000000000
00000111111111100000
00001111111111100000
00001111111111100000
00001111111111000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
```

## Specifications

- You may take input for the diagram as a string separated by newlines or obvious equivalent
- You will receive a coordinate on the loop (0 or 1 indexed) as part of your input.  You may place your origin at any place you wish.  You may take this coordinate in `(<row>, <column>)`, `(<column>, <row>)` or as the linear position on the string.  You may receive these data in any reasonable method.  All characters on the loop will be the same as the character at that index.
- Preferred output is a 2 dimensional array of truthy and falsy values, however strings of `1` and `0` separated by newlines or any obvious equivalent of the later two are accepted.  The inside and outside must have different truth values but it does not matter which is which.
- A loop is defined as a group of characters such that they are all the same character (*e.g. `@`*) and so that every character in the loop has a path to the original character (The character at the coordinate of input) that only passes through that same character (Taxicab geometry *No diagonals*).
- The inside is all the loop itself and the places that cannot reach the edge of the diagram without crossing the loop.
- The outside is everywhere else
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

## Test Cases

[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Sth0V6QT)

Comment: Are we allowed to take the diagram as a matrix of characters, sth. like `[['.', '.'],['.', '@']]` instead of a string with newlines?

Comment: @hbaderts That is an obvious equivalent

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks for the additional test case! I would however recommend to put them into a snippet or in a gist / pastebin, in order to make the challenge a bit more decluttered=)

Comment: Can we assume the input will be at least 2x2? Or if it¡s for example 1xN (a single line) how is insideness defined?

Comment: @LuisMendo For a line the inside will be the "loop" and nothing else

Comment: If I take the input as a linear coordinate into the 2D char array, can it be [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) (i.e. down, then across)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Go ahead.  I don't care how you take the data in I am not concerned with data processing but more the underlying algorithm.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks! Anyway my algorithm was flawed because it assumed the loop was convex :-(

Comment: can there be more than one loop in an image?

Comment: @Razetime It depends on what you mean by "more than one loop" I suppose.  Have a look at the testcases they might answer your question.  But if they don't if you reword the question I can answer and add a test case if needed.

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB, <s>163 159 146</s> 78 bytes

```
function m=f(m,y,x);[~,i]=bwfill(m~=m(y,x),x,y,8);m=m*0;m(i)=1;m=bwfill(m,'h')
```

Thanks @rahnema1 for -66 bytes!!!

Now it does work on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#jZC9boMwFIV3nuIuiTFiaNUMlSwP6VapVZdsUQYMJrEK1wibBJa@Or2GkDZSh2Ih@fh85/inlnuWrKeR3P5k0kxEbJaTu04WbrZu@n4s1sLO2KR@W4txpe6tfxROpewgoqiXTyIa5CNNV2WHuTcWQckyrtM@HbiAVYelbX2HmdfVAAvjIM8QrQelwTU6N6XRBRiE3esHZA78SQ@AmtacbrKWwlCaSrtoRYnKXgIAzrcGj8BOlhwWGqe6E@2nkaLeksdC6/t297Z9oXCIZe2xqzV62AS2q4qQouzzDwlxbhE1HfVs/ACFLk0oVHQB2@pjazss4OxAZfnnrPgo/vj2KjVFf5DqQqev4vpL1vGQ9jw8TrrhQkmVPAgVE8TpEdUCqvR6KS7GwrgmVnz8Bg) BUT a few adjustments were needed, as MATLAB and Octave are not entirely compatible.

#### Explanation

First we make a binary image that just masks all the characters that are equal to the initial character. Then we determine the connected component the initial character is in.

```
% determine the connected component that is contains initial character
        
[~,i]=bwfill(m~=m(y,x),x,y,8);     % i contains the indices of the connected component
m=m*0;m(i)=1;                      % create an image of the connected component
```

After that we create an image of that connected component and apply fill all the "holes" in the image.

```
m=bwfill(m,'h')
```

Comment: I think for golfing  Octave  is better so you may reduce it to at least 72 bytes

Comment: @rahnema1 I already started in MATLAB, so I'm not gonna change this submission now, but thanks for the suggestion=)

Answer (score 5):

### MATLAB: 67 bytes

```
function A=f(A,r,c),A=bwlabel(A==A(r,c),4);A=imfill(A==A(r,c),'h');
```

A couple caveats:

- `A` is assumed to be a character array.
- Indices in MATLAB are 1-based, with rows indexed first. It is assumed these changes would be made to the function input (i.e. the question example would be called as `output = f(A,2,8)`).
- `bwlabel` and `imfill` are part of the Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: welcome to codegolf!

Comment: @rahnema1: Amazed I didn't visit sooner, since I did some golfing on SO before this site was born.